# Display and calculate 3 different prices for every user in Ubercart

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, cck, ubercart, drupal-commerce

Is there any way to display 3 different prices for every user(not per role etc)? Every product should have 3 prices: default price, wholesale price and dealer price. So I should display all of them on product page and calculate 3 total prices for every type of price. P.S.: we can add CCK field, but how to calculate total prices for each of them?
P.P.S: users are anonimous, it means I do not know whether or not the user is authorized. So I should always show and calculate 3 prices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

THis module does exactly what you're looking for, I;ve used it before for wholesale and retail prices

https://drupal.org/project/uc_price_per_role

Comment: If users are anonimous? I do not know whether or not the user is authorized. So I should always show and calculate 3 prices. Can I achive the goal via this module?

Comment: You could possibly do this, but why would you want to display all three prices? Can you exaplain your business scenario?

Comment: Potential buyers of wholesale and dealers will be able to estimate the approximate benefit of becoming wholesale or dealer.

Comment: Looking at the module page it says that it comes with a block so you can switch between prices, you could make that block available to anonymous users.